# What body parts can I use to deliver a spell whose range is "touch"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, touch-attacks

Within a pure Pathfinder game ...

When delivering a melee touch spell can I use any body part? (hand, elbow, foot, head), any body part I could attack with or must I use my hand?

If I am a witch with the [Prehensile hair hex](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch#TOC-Hex) can I use that to deliver touch attacks?

Answer (score 11):

Touch attacks can be made with any body part, though there is no particular advantage to doing so in most cases. The Prehensile Hair Hex, of course, gives a reason to do so, and yes, it can be used to make touch attacks.

Comment: There might be RP reasons, like stumbling into someone to discreetly deliver a touch-range spell with your shoulder while your hands are tied behind your back...

Comment: @Tacroy, just remember that many of the spells are going to have a somatic component so hands tied will cause a problem.  Also, discretion could be more difficult for spells requiring Vocal components, my fav way of dealing with this is to speak in a different language.  Further, spells with Material or Focus will present their own problems.  Not knocking what u said at all, just things to be mindful of.

Comment: A readied spell should alleviate those problems above in most circumstances

Comment: I would add that changing form (such as polymorph or other effects) would also give you more options like tails, wings, etc. to deliver touch spells with (assuming you can cast spells in that form or have a touch spell ready before gaining that form). The only exception to this would be specific exceptions mentioned in the text; Gaseous Form, for example.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can! This is helpful both for Witches with the Prehensile Hair Hex, and for some weird spell-discharging situations wherein a multiclassed monk has the ability to discharge touch attacks through the use of Unarmed Strike. This allows the monk to utilize the spell while their hands are full. Similar tricks may be done with natural weapons, if one is so inclined.

Comment: Even if you couldn't generally do something like this, presumably the Monk's special ability to make Unarmed Strikes with any body part would allow a Monk/spellcaster to make touch attacks with any body part as well. At least, for any reasonable DM.

Comment: @KRyan Good point, don't know why that didn't occur to me.